# Flexbox is a framework?

Tags: css, frameworks, flexbox

I was talking to someone about Flexbox, and he said Flexbox is a library/light-framework which sounds a bit weird to me and now I'm confused.

Is it a framework or not?

Comment: No, it is a grid system in css based on flex display property, maybe that is what he was talking about. Here you have some details: http://flexboxgrid.com/

Comment: Flex layout is many things, but it is *not a grid system*. It can align elements in rows and columns, but not grids. That's one reason why the W3C is developing [**grid layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

Comment: @Michael_B question was about "Flexbox", not "flex" - it is not the same

Comment: @Joint, I was never talking about *flex*, only *flexbox* (which is the same as *flex layout*). I'm aware the *flex* (the Apache framework) and *flexbox* (CSS) are totally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is just pure CSS, not a framework

> The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the
>   flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in
>   that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins
>   collapse with the margins of its contents

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox is a commonly used term that refers to the [***CSS Flexible Box Layout***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), which is a CSS technology. It is just plain CSS.

Of course, in the same way jQuery is derived from JavaScript, there are various frameworks that have been derived from flexbox (e.g., [Angular](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html), [Bulma](http://bulma.io/), [Flexbox Grid](http://flexboxgrid.com/), [Basis](https://getbasis.github.io/), etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. According to wikipedia, a framework is software used to alleviate a lot of the work associated with web development [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework). I would not consider flex a framework simply because it is default/native/included browser behavior. No external software is needed to use flex in your website.

I don't think there is one definition for what a framework is, but I have never considered default html/css behavior to be a framework. To me, a framework is code that I have to install or download to be able to use in my website.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it sounded so weird when he told me that it is a library/framework because it's already part of CSS, it isn't added behavior like a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 (unlike its predecessors) is *a collection of specifications*.

**CSS Flexible Box Layout** (or *Flexbox*) is one of these CSS specifications.

Others include:

- *CSS Color Level 3*
- *CSS Selectors Level 3*
- *CSS Media Queries*
- *CSS Multi-column Layout*
- *CSS Shapes Level 1*
- *CSS Grid Layout Level 1*
- *CSS Writing Modes Level 3*

and so on.

---

For the **entire range** of CSS Specs currently completed or in development, see:

- [Descriptions of all CSS specifications](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html)
- [CSS Current Work](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) (summary)